# Make a Launcher for a Privileged Terminal Command

Tags: command-line, gksu

I want to make a Launcher that will do privileged (requires root) commands, but I don't want to see the terminal or have to type my password into the terminal. So I found the command, `gksudo` that allows me to enter my password so that I can escalate my privilege level. Now I want to couple this, so that I can change the partition priority using this command `cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 0 /dev/sda` (this command is privileged) and have it automatically reboot from this one launcher.

I setup a Luncher like this:

**Name**: ChromeOS

**Description**:

**Command**: `gksudo gnome-terminal -e "cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 0 /dev/sda;reboot"`

**Comment**:

But it does not work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a gnome-terminal while running commands with gksudo .

just add  this to the launcher .

```
gksudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 0 /dev/sda;reboot
```

Comment: I will give this a shot after I'm done watching the F1 (I have to switch to Ubuntu to play AVI files ... I really think CrOS should have support for AVI files out of the box, but I digress.)

Comment: That did not work for me.